# ERROR: Cannot find module 'fast-safe-stringify' when I run firebase init

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native

I already ran npm install fast-safe-stringify and shows that it is installed in package JSON.

I have tried deleting package-lock and reinstalling firebase-tools and fast-safe-stringify but it still shows the error

My error

```
Require stack:
- C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\logform\json.js
- C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\logger.js
- C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\create-logger.js
- C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\lib\winston.js
- C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\logger.js
- C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mfirebase-tools←[24m\node_modules\←[4mlogform←[24m\json.js:5:23)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\logform\\json.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\winston\\lib\\winston\\logger.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\winston\\lib\\winston\\create-logger.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\winston\\lib\\winston.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\logger.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\index.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\bin\\firebase.js'←[39m
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was that installation of fast-safe-stringfy was not global so I ran

```
npm i -g fast-safe-stringify
```

and it started working